# Blocking I/O calls in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, io, operating-system, blocking

Are all blocking I/O calls in Linux somehow wrapped around read() and write() (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Primitives.html)?

My use case will then be to intercept these functions calls and execute code before and after them to count how I/O is utilized in a sample program.

Comment: What blocking I/O calls do you have in mind specifically?

Comment: Disk I/O, socket I/O, etc.. Basically any blocking I/O calls that a basic multithreaded server would make :)

Comment: You should check the manual page for the write/read family of functions, however I'm not 100% certain that this covers all I/O calls.

Answer (score 0):

> Are all blocking I/O calls in Linux somehow wrapped around read() and
>   write()
>   (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Primitives.html)?

No. Since you have in mind also socket I/O, cf. [**Transferring Data**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Transferring-Data.html) (from the same manual):

> There are also some I/O modes that are specific to socket operations.
>   In order to specify these modes, you must use the `recv`
>   and `send` functions instead of the more generic
>   `read` and `write` functions.